# Android : Intercepting bluetooth headset's Answer button

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have been trying to intercept my bluetooth headset's Answer button in vain. I am able to get the incoming ringtone in my headset and once I answer the call from my app, I am able to hear on the headset. But, I am not able to figure out how to intercept the Answer button in my app so that I can pick up the call as well using headset.

My phone is with Jelly Bean OS. I have tried using register media button receiver and also a plain receiver with IntentFilter ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED and again with ACTION_CALL_BUTTON, but nothing seems to work. Please let me know how I could get this working. Appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To get Bluetooth device working first you need to add permissions in your application's Manifest file:

```
<manifest ... >
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
  ...
</manifest>
```

which I'm sure, you must have done already.

Now to control bluetooth headset, you can use bluetooth headset service:

An example code snippet:

```
BluetoothHeadset mBluetoothHeadset;

// Get the default adapter
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
            mBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
        }
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
            mBluetoothHeadset = null;
        }
    }
};

// Establish connection to the proxy.
mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(context, mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);

// ... call functions on mBluetoothHeadset

// Close proxy connection after use.
mBluetoothAdapter.closeProfileProxy(mBluetoothHeadset);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Yes, I have made the declarations in the manifest but am not clear on how to use the BluetoothHeadset and the Adapter. I am sorry but I am not able to understand your code clearly, where do I add the events to capture button click on the headset ? Is it some event that BluetoothHeadset provides ? I checked but could not find which method I have to use to capture button click events.

Comment: Has anyone done anything like this in Cordova phonegap.  I am looking to capture the call or hook button activity.